# Integral of $\frac{1}{x-a}\frac{1}{e^{x-a}-1}$

Tags: integration, contour-integration

For positive powers of $x$, I know how to do this integral, but with $x$ at the denominator? Is there a way to at least isolate the divergence, or to do this using Cauchy's theorem? The integral is for $$|x^2-a^2|\leq 1$$ but I would like to know how to do it in several cases, indefinite and for $0$ to $\infty$. $x$ is real.

Comment: You can't find a primitive written only with elementary functions.

Comment: so, is there a form with a finite and divergent part, in general?

Answer (score 0):

There is no closed-form antiderivative.  Moreover the pole at $x=a$ has order $2$, so it is non-integrable.